# C# GetForegroundWindow() returns the same result for multiple windows, EnumWindows does not really return that # at all

Tags: c#, step-into, reversing

C#'s `GetForegroundWindow()` returns the same result for multiple windows, `EnumWindows` does not really return that window at all. Each process really has its own tier.

I've also went through both of the `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` functions and enumerated through them with `GetChildWindows()`, but still they don't return the same window as `GetForegroundWindow()`.

How do you properly start with `GetForegroundWindow()` and turn it into what you'd retrieve from a proper `EnumWindows`?

Goal: `GetForegroundWindow` + enumerate properly to retrieve proper top-level handles (all tabs in chrome, your project form(s)), but without having to sift through the mess `GetAllWindows()` brings you.  Thanks.

```
private ArrayList GetAllWindows()
{
    var windowHandles = new ArrayList();
    EnumedWindow callBackPtr = GetWindowHandle;
    EnumWindows(callBackPtr, windowHandles);

    foreach (IntPtr windowHandle in windowHandles.ToArray())
    {
        EnumChildWindows(windowHandle, callBackPtr, windowHandles);
    }

    return windowHandles;
}

private delegate bool EnumedWindow(IntPtr handleWindow, ArrayList handles);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumedWindow lpEnumFunc, ArrayList lParam);

[DllImport("user32")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumedWindow callback, ArrayList lParam);

List<IntPtr> ids = new List<IntPtr>();

private bool GetWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle, ArrayList windowHandles)
{
    windowHandles.Add(windowHandle);
    listBox1.Items.Add(windowHandle);
    //ids.Add(GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: do you mean that the result from `EnumWindows` does not contain the window returned from `GetForegroundWindow`?

Comment: not exactly.. it gets better results, but not distinct results.

Comment: Anyone given this a go?

Comment: Can you clarify the use of the [step-into] and [reversing] tags for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use for C++ in Windows:

```
TCHAR buf[255];    
HWND foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
DWORD* processID = new DWORD;
GetWindowText(foregroundWindow, buf, 255);
GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindow, processID);
DWORD p = *processID;
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                              PROCESS_VM_READ,
                              FALSE, p);
TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH];

if (NULL != hProcess )
{
    HMODULE hMod;
    DWORD cbNeeded;

    if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod),
                             &cbNeeded) )
    {
        GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
                           sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
    }
}
CloseHandle(hProcess);
long pid = (long)p;
```

I understand your application is C#, but you can perhaps use some of these Windows API calls to get the information you need. Let me know if there is anything I can do to further explain the code.